# Sticky text in listbox - wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

I add items successfully to the listbox but instead normal space between them , they stick together. Can anyone help me solve that problem?

```
 <ListBox Name="mylistbox" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--<StackPanel Name="s1">-->
                            <Grid Name="g1">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding redni2}"  FontSize="26" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ime}"  FontSize="26" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding broj2}"  FontSize="26" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ukupno2}"  FontSize="26" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
                                </Grid>
                            <!--</StackPanel>-->
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Comment: you mean between TextBlocks or Items in the ListBox?

How about adding <Grid Name="g1" Margin = "10">

Answer (score 0):

Use ListBox.ItemContainerStyle property. Try this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,9.5">
                <Grid Name="g1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="111" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="222" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="333" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="444" FontSize="26" Grid.Column="3"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```